# Send info from ffmpeg to text file & then parsing into a new file

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, video, cmd.exe

I am trying to scan a directory of .mkv files and output the volume information to out.txt and then parse out.txt for volume_max and send it to log.txt using

```
for %i in (*.mkv) do ffmpeg -i "%i" -af "volumedetect" -vn -sn -dn -f 1>> out.txt 2>&1 | findstr max_volume out.txt > log.txt
```

but I keep getting the error ***Missing argument for option 'f', Error splitting the argument list: Invalid argument*** for each file when it runs the ffmpeg command.

I do get the out.txt file but it's not complete information for each file that's processed.  Also, the log.txt file is always 0 bytes, I assume because out.txt doesn't get to the point for each file of getting the max_volume information.

I know it's got to be something simple but I can't see it.  Can anyone shed a bit of light on what I might be doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: On Windows or Linux?

Comment: Would something like this be the expected output on the log file: https://i.ibb.co/Lgx0L1Q/Max-Volume.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to drag and drop the folder containing the *.mkv files to the batch script. It took like 1 minute for each video on my weak laptop.

You open notepad and paste the code bellow on it and save it with the name that you want but with a *.bat extension.

%%a represents the file name on the script and %%b the max_volume part...

```
@echo off

if exist "%~1" if not exist "%~1\" exit

pushd "%~1"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.mkv') do for /f "tokens=2 delims=]" %%b in ('ffmpeg -hide_banner -nostats -i "%%a" -af "volumedetect" -vn -dn -sn -f null nul 2^>^&1 ^|find /i "max_volume"') do >>Max_Volume.log echo %%a -^> %%b
```

[GIF Link](https://i.ibb.co/Lgx0L1Q/Max-Volume.gif)

Comment: Thank you for the help!  That worked perfectly.  I just wish I understood more about what it actually did.  :)

Comment: @lo-oL only proceed if a folder was dragged to the batch, if it is a file than "%a\" is not true...

Comment: @lo-ol Doesn't work like that, in that case the batch closes no matter if you drag a file or a folder to it....

Comment: if exist .\"%~1"\. (pushd "%~1") else (exit) nesse caso ele fecha sempre...